# I want to use Mysql View with laravel, but i need know is it good , or there's any in exchange for mysql views?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I need some help i am using laravel to build restful api , i need some thing to get specific data from database, like mysql views but i don't if it's agood way or there's another perfect method to do that,
thanks

Comment: First of all, welcome to SF. Please specify more concretely what do you need to do?

Comment: This is a very broad question. Are you asking if Laravel works well with MySQL views or if views are going to be a good option for you to use? What are you wanting to use the views for?